# Visitors getting security certificate error when visiting

Tags: ssl-certificate

When visitors try to visit a website of mine, they get this error indicating that the "site is not secure":

> Error Code: DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID

I used the automatic SSL setup `certbot` from Let's Encrypt.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Is it possible that the issue is that their browsers are caching a previous SSL that is no longer on the domain?

Comment: Your certificate works fine for me. My guess would be that some of your visitors use outdated browsers that don't have current CAs.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Awesome, thanks for the response! So the best I would be able to do in this situation is find a more established CA? Because the website is for a client and she says that a lot of her customers (in reality could just be 1 or 2) are getting hit by this.

Comment: On my win8 and IE I got the certificate warning, I guess it's related to IE

Comment: Why did you remove the name from your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to include the `www` prefix in your certificate request. The cert only works for the domain without www.

See documentation of certbot: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#changing-a-certificate-s-domains

In the common case of a domain with and without www, you do:

```
certbot certonly --cert-name example.com -d www.example.com,example.com
```

Comment: So I should just simply create an additional certificate for `www`?

Comment: @X33 you can maybe just change your cert to include www. and the domain name

Comment: The exact operations depend on the service you use to provision the certificate from letsencrypt. I can only refer you to the documentation for certbot.

Comment: Using the documentation you linked, I just ran `certbot certonly --cert-name mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com`

Comment: Caution. You should run `certbot certonly --cert-name mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com,mydomain.com`, unless your site can only be reached on www.mydomain.com.